# Mlflow - empty artifact folder

Tags: python-3.x, mlflow

All,

I started the **mlflow server** as below. I do see the **backend store** containing the expected metadata. However, the **artifact folder** is ***empty*** despite many runs.

```
> mlflow server --backend-store-uri mlflow_db --default-artifact-root
> ./mlflowruns --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

The mlflow ui has the below message for the artifacts section:

> ```
>               No Artifacts Recorded
>  Use the log artifact APIs to store file outputs from MLflow runs.
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
grajee

Comment: show the code that is used for runs

Comment: This is the code that I used:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/manage-your-machine-learning-lifecycle-with-mlflow-in-python-d678d5f3c682

Comment: have you logged the artifacts at all? mlflow.log_artifacts()?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that

"--backend-store-uri mlflow_db" was pointing to D:\python\Pythonv395\Scripts\mlflow_db

and

"--default-artifact-root ./mlflowruns" was pointing to D:\DataEngineering\MlFlow\Wine Regression\mlflowruns which is the project folder.

I was able to point both the output to one folder with the following syntax
**file:/D:/DataEngineering/MlFlow/Wine Regression**

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to log artifacts to your server with local file system as object storage, you should specify `--serve-artifact --artifact-destination file:/path/to/your/desired/location` instead of just a vanilla path.